# Change permissions to remove the lock from files

Tags: permissions

I recently restored my Ubuntu 20.04 pc from a backup. Many of the restored files have a lock on them and I can only open them as root.  How can I change this so that the "root-lock" is removed?
Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Did you run deja-dup as root when restoring or backing up?

Comment: Check the owner of the directories. If necessary use `chown` with `sudo` to correct the ownership. (Don't forget to change both the user and the group.)

Comment: I am the owner of the directories - I am the only user on this pc (it is my pc - private) - but I have to open them as root because somehow I have put that lock on them. I now wan't to remove the "root-only" lock but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Enter the command:

```
$ id
```

Note the names for `uid` and `gid` in the output which should be shown in parentheses.

Run the following commands:

```
$ cd
$ sudo chown -R 'uid':'gid' firefox hplib-3*
```

Here, replace `'uid'` and `'gid'` with the values you have obtained from the `id` command output. For example:

```
$ sudo chown -R john:doe firefox hplib-3*
```

Comment: Wonderful! That worked. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Perhaps, for others, I should clarify that the actual cmd I used was: $ sudo chown -R userid:groupid /home/userid/